# What type of mirage is this?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, atmospheric-science, geometric-optics

I am very new to the world of mirages and would like some information as to the type of mirage in this picture which I took this morning. It is the cargo ship African Kalmia which passed my location at about 10am (UK time) this morning. I also have some great video of it moving along above the sea but I can't upload the file here. I have taken a picture of a superior mirage from the same location which I uploaded to this site last month, it was of another cargo ship with an inverted image on top. In that picture there was a clear heat haze line but today there wasn't any visible heat haze so I'm somewhat confused. 
 [image]

[image]

Comment: [African Kalmia](http://www.cargos-paquebots.net/Revue%20de%20presse/0000_IMAGES-21/396-African_Kalmia.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

All mirages work on the same principle as fiber optics: a negative gradient of refraction index will create a region of small grazing angles with almost [total reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection) which confines light rays into the refraction index region with larger index.

Some cargo ships have multiple crane towers, so it looks like you are seeing only the top of those towers reflected on the mirage reflection surfaces
[image: cargo ship with cranes]